# Bash: Git submodule foreach?

Tags: git, bash, foreach, git-submodules

I have `sup` aliased to `submodule foreach 'git co master; git up'` (`co` & `up` are aliases for `checkout` & `pull --rebase`, respectively.).

How do add a condition so that if the submodule name is `Libraries/JSONKit`, it checks out the branch named `experimental`, instead of `master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to `.git/config`:

```
[alias]
    sup = "submodule foreach 'if [ $name == \"Libraries/JSONKit\" ]; then git co experimental; else git co master; fi; git up'"
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted although it is the validated answer? Didn't tried the exact command myself, though adding an alias was very useful in my case to allow a complex LFS command to be easily launched in git foreach : [alias] track-large = !"git st --porcelain --ignore-submodules | grep -v \"D \" | awk '{ l=length($0); s=substr($0,4,l-1); print s}' | sed -n 's/\\(\\(.* -> *\\)\\|\\)\\(.*\\)/\\3/p' | xargs -I{} find {} -size +300k | xargs -I{} git lfs track \"{}\""

Answer (score 16):

The script passwd to `git submodule` is run with it's working directory set to the top of the given submodule...so you can simply look at `pwd` to see if you're in you're in the particular submodule.  However, if you take some time to read the `git submodule` documentation, it turns out to be even easier:

```
foreach
    Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule. The 
    command has access to the variables $name, $path, $sha1
    and $toplevel: $name is the name of the relevant submodule section in 
    .gitmodules, $path is the name of the submodule directory
    relative to the superproject, $sha1 is the commit as recorded in the superproject, 
    and $toplevel is the absolute path to the top-level of the superproject.
```

So you can do something like this:

```
git submodule foreach '[ "$path" = "Libraries/JSONKit" ] \
  && branch=experimental \
  || branch=master; git co $branch'
```

Comment: for any googlers out there, I adapted this for nested submodules `git submodule foreach 'git submodule init && git submodule update'` - found it makes live easier for projects with plenty of plugins ;)

Comment: submodule foreach also supports `--recursive` so you can walk nested submodules with the same shell command too.

Answer (score 4):

[larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8365230/6309) uses:

```
git submodule foreach '[ "$path" = "Libraries/JSONKit" ]
```

But it should now (2020) be

```
git submodule foreach '[ "$sm_path" = "Libraries/JSONKit" ]
```

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), The bulk of "[`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) " has been rewritten in C, and its documentation evolves.

See [commit fc1b924](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc1b9243cd5d51ae455272f1f953d4002294edee) (10 May 2018), and [commit b6f7ac8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6f7ac8fd561d6df9c76009898daf96a93765ffc), [commit f0fd0dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0fd0dc5c5fcc066fc2e0b7dc1e809cb2d219ee3), [commit c033a2f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c033a2f62dda774de8cccc83b7f1918377995d6c) (09 May 2018) by [Prathamesh Chavan (`pratham-pc`)](https://github.com/pratham-pc).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ea27893](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea27893a65cc41cad2710466aa6a58866ff22f1e), 25 Jun 2018)</sup>

> ### [`submodule foreach`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0fd0dc5c5fcc066fc2e0b7dc1e809cb2d219ee3): document '`$sm_path`' instead of '$path'
>
> As using a variable '$path' may be harmful to users due to capitalization issues, see [64394e3ae9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64394e3ae9194836ffd4068006bbdd5ad9810a4b) ("[`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).sh: Don't use $path variable in `eval_gettext` string", 2012-04-17, Git v1.7.11-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ea07808c1eaae9f819c37dd65affe674564627e) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa39b858a35d99135e1403575a358b97d26ff466)).
>   Adjust the documentation to advocate for using `$sm_path`, which contains the same value.
>   We still make the '`path`' variable available, and document it as a **deprecated synonym** of '`sm_path`'.
>
> Discussed-with: Ramsay Jones

The [`Documentation/git-submodule#foreach`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f0fd0dc5c5fcc066fc2e0b7dc1e809cb2d219ee3/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L184-L197) now includes:

> ### `foreach [--recursive] <command>`:
>
> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule.
>
> The command has access to the variables `$name`, `$sm_path`, `$sha1` and `$toplevel`:
>
> - `$name` is the name of the relevant submodule section in `.gitmodules`.
> - `$sm_path` is the path of the submodule as recorded in the immediate superproject,
> - `$sha1` is the commit as recorded in the immediate superproject, and
> - `$toplevel` is the absolute path to the top-level of the immediate superproject.
>
> **Note that to avoid conflicts with '`$PATH`' on Windows, the '`$path`' variable is now a deprecated synonym of '`$sm_path`' variable**.